# How to open the native cmd.exe window in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to open a cmd.exe window with the project root directory as it's current directory.

Here is my elisp code:

```
(defun open-cmd-and-cd-to-project-root()
  (interactive)
  (projectile-mode t)
  (cd (projectile-get-project-root))
  (shell))
```

It opens a cmd shell in an Emacs buffer . But I want it opens a new native cmd.exe window running in Windows rather than a buffer running in Emacs. How can I do that?

Comment: can you rephrase the question ? I do not understand the question.

Comment: @alinsoar: In gvim.exe, I can open a new cmd terminal window by execute the command `:!cmd` . How can I do that in Emacs?

Comment: first, I never used windows of bill gates, so I do not know windows. second. `"open a new cmd terminal window by execute the command :!cmd"` is not a correct expression, so I have to guess.

Do you want to run a command using `Meta-!` ?

Comment: z_axis: I do not understand what he wants. I also supposed that he wants "M-!".

Comment: @alinsoar:  In Ubuntu I can launch the real terminal by `Meta-!` `gnome-terminal` , but I can't launch the real terminal by `Meta-!` `cmd` on Windows.

Comment: @z_axis: I have tried `M-! cmd `. It launches the cmd shell in the minibuffer . I want it launches a real cmd window, just like launches cmd.exe by click the cmd.exe icon from the Start Menu in Windows.

Comment: @wvxvw: thanks! it works except two annoying security warning box will pop up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this:

```
(let ((proc (start-process "cmd" nil "cmd.exe" "/C" "start" "cmd.exe")))
  (set-process-query-on-exit-flag proc nil))
```

The `set-process-query-on-exit-flag` to `nil` is so it won't bother on closing `emacs` (we can't kill it anyway).

Comment: @angus Could you tell me how to make a function from your code, so that I can put it in my .emacs file and bind a key to it? I'm lacking of programming skills, unfortunately.

Comment: @KeksDose Just put it inside a `defun` form: `(defun start-cmd () (interactive)` *my code here* `)`. Then call it with `M-x start-cmd`.

Comment: Works very well, so it is easy to start latexmk on windows in a command window. That makes it easy to watch pdflatex running...

Comment: To open `cmd` to a specific directory, do: `(defun start-cmd ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((proc (start-process "cmd" nil "cmd.exe" "/C" "start" "cmd.exe" "/K" "cd" "c:\\starting\\folder")))
    (set-process-query-on-exit-flag proc nil)))`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the system configuration, the `start` command will spin up a native terminal or explorer window.

I believe the choice is down to whether you allow multiple instances of the `explorer` shell (the file browser), but some other config might be involved (Local Group Policy, etc.)

<kbd>M-!</kbd> `start`

**Your confusion** stems from the fact that <kbd>M-!</kbd> creates an ad-hoc shell for executing commands by the default processor (`cmd.exe`, or rather `cmdproxy.exe` in this case), so starting a shell *from a shell* will not yield a separate terminal window.

`start` is a `cmd.exe` builtin, which opens a new shell window (again, subject to system configuration, as well as arguments passed to it).